# List of objects related to another list of objects

Tags: apex, soql, salesforce-id, query

```
    List<Id> quotaIdList = new List<Id>();
    List<User> quotaOwnerList = new List<User>();

    List<Order__c> orderList = [SELECT Id, Sales_Director__c, Quota_Name_Qtr__c, Order_Total__c
                      FROM Order__c
                      WHERE Ship_Date__c >= THIS_QUARTER AND Ship_Date__c < NEXT_QUARTER];

    for(Order__c o : orderList) quotaIdList.add(o.Quota_Name_Qtr__c);

    List<Quota__c> quotaList = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Quota_Amount__c
                      FROM Quota__c
                      WHERE Id IN :quotaIdList];
```

I'd like to create a list of Quota's based on the contents of orderList in my example.  Is there a better way to do this, avoiding creating the intermediary list of Id's?  In this example, Quota_Amount__c is the Id of a Quota object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the list with a single SOQL query.  Try something like this

```
List<Quota__c> quotaList = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Quota_Amount__c
                               FROM Quota__c
                               WHERE Id IN (Select Quota_Name_Qtr__c 
                                                From Order__c
                                                Where Ship_Date__c >= THIS_QUARTER 
                                                AND Ship_Date__c < NEXT_QUARTER
                                              )
                           ];
```

This is an oldie but goodie from Jeff Douglas on SOQL queries.  There is a piece in there around semi-join queries such as the one above.  I would take a look, its a great resource

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/02/22/soql-how-i-query-with-thee-let-me-count-the-ways/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'll take a look at that blog post.

Comment: No prob.  Glad to help  :)